# jQuery table - How to write text in cell depending on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table with `class=".table"` contain 4 columns with classes as below

•.delete //this is checkbox column ,

•.Id,

•.description,

•.flag

and have a button with `class=".savebtn"`.
What I need: when user check any checkbox cell in `".delete"` column update flag cell in the same row with text "d" then delete this checked row when user click `".savebtn"`.

I Try this code but not working please help me:

```
 $('.savebtn').click(function() {
  $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find($("input[name='delete[]']:checked")).each(function() {
      $(this).change(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".flag input").val("d"));  
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       });
   });
  });
 });
```

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").find(".flag input").val("d"));`  should be `$(this).closest("tr").find("input.flag").val("d"));` if the class is for the input

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cg42mnpo/

Comment: i dont see any class flag from there

Comment: sorry I forget to add this is the update: https://jsfiddle.net/cg42mnpo/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('.savebtn').click(function() {
  $('.delete :checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();
});

$('.delete :checkbox').change(function() {
  var d = this.checked ? 'd' : '';
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".flag").val(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Flag</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="delete"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>any data</td>
        <td>any data</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="flag" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="delete"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>any data</td>
        <td>any data</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="flag"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="delete"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>any data</td>
        <td>any data</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="flag" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="savebtn" value="Save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

the element attribute should be `class="table"`
like this

### HTML

```
<p class="myClass"></p>
```

### JQuery

```
$(".myClass").click( ...
```

### EDIT

you can use a simpler function:

```
$('.savebtn').click(function() {
  $("td input.delete:checked").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

what it does is when the button with the class "savebtn" is clicked, it finds all input elements with a class "delete" that are checked. For each of them it finds the closest tr and deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.savebtn').click(function() {
  $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').each(function() {
    console.log($(this))
    $(this).find($(".delete:checked")).each(function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text.flag").val("d");
      //$(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class='cf-table-block'>
  <tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Flag</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" class="delete">
    </td>
    <td>any Data</td>
    <td>any Data</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="flag" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" class="delete">
    </td>
    <td>any Data</td>
    <td>any Data</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="flag" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" class="delete">
    </td>
    <td>any Data</td>
    <td>any Data</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="flag" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <input class="savebtn" style="width: 65px; font-size: 16px;" type="button" value="Save">
```

```
$('.savebtn').click(function() {
  $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').each(function() {//added the class in html
    console.log($(this))
    $(this).find($(".delete:checked")).each(function() {//no attr name but class
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text.flag").val("d");//input type text with class flag
      //$(this).closest('tr').remove();//commented to see the letter d
    });
  });

});
```

Do this

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cg42mnpo/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$('.savebtn').click(function() {
  $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find($("input[name='delete[]']:checked")).each(function() {
        if($(this).closest("tr").find(".flag input").text().indexOf("d") > -1)){ 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
         }
      });
  });
 });
```